# How to add Spring Boot Actuator to a Spring application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In the "Bootiful" Applications with Spring Boot Spring One 2014 section(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCyYEVRZISk), Josh mentioned that it is easy to add the Boot Actuator to a Spring (non-bootiful) application. I assume that an Actuator configuration is needed somehow, but can't find how it shall be done.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the starter to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

... and the endpoints such as `/health` will be available.

Comment: Not quite. Not if it's not a Spring Boot application. You would have to grab the `Endpoint*AutoConfigurations` and all their dependencies and include them in your app.

Comment: Rather than including all the `Endpoint*AutoConfiguration` classes, I think you should be able to just annotate your `@Configuration` class with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. Your app is becoming somewhat "Bootiful" at that point, though.

Comment: I guess it depends on whether the intention is to keep everything Boot out of the app, except for Actuator. Or whether it's acceptable to move the app forward a bit.

Comment: I already have the Actuator dependence in my application. And I can't see Actuator URLs configured during the starting up which indicates Actuator doesn't work. @DaveSyer Shall I do something like what is said on http://www.leveluplunch.com/blog/2013/12/22/configure-spring-actuator-outside-of-spring-boot/ to grab the Enpint*AutoConfigurations and their dependences? The Java configuration mentioned on the blog can't be compiled. Also, my application has defined some URLs like /{domainObjectEntityAttribute}. I need to customize Actuator's URLs to avoid URL collisions.

Comment: Are you avoiding adding `@EndpointAutoConfiguration` to one of your `@Configuration` classes?